# Listing all packages installing into a specific directory

Tags: apt, apt-file

How to search for all packages installing files into a specific directory.

E.g. I want to list all packages which are writing files into the `/etc/apparmor.d` directory.

Answer (score 2):

For the listing limited to the set of *installed* packages only:

```
dpkg -S /etc/apparmor.d/
```

This is helpful when tracking down which installed package(s) placed a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

First install this package

```
sudo apt install apt-file
```

and update the database

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Next open a terminal and paste/write the following code into it:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
cat << EOF > ~/.local/bin/apt-filesearch
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-file search \$1 | cut -f 1 -d ":" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
EOF
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/apt-filesearch
```

This will copy the script apt-filesearch into the `~/.local/bin` directory.

Now you search for all packages installing stuff into the e.g. `/etc/apparmor.d/` directory:

```
apt-filesearch /etc/apparmor
```

This script is also nice if you are searching for libs or header files.